# UNIX -killing pid and passing argument in ksh

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, kill

I am new to UNIX. I want to kill pid of file "File_name" and then I have to run "Recycle_All" script which by default takes the argument 'y'.

```
#!/bin/ksh
ps -aef | grep "File_name" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
/directory>./Recycle y
exit
```

I am not able to pass 'y' as argument.
Also how should I verify that the pids have been killed by the above command.

The error is:

```
usage: kill [ -signo ] pid ...

./soap_rec.ksh[x]: ./Recycle_All: cannot create
```

Comment: While passing the argument it shows any error or warning message. If you used `$1` inside the script for check the first argument.

Comment: I suggest you to filter out grep process itself like: `ps -aef | grep "File_name" | grep -v grep | awk ...`.   And you could check if pid exists using `ps -p PID`.

Comment: Have a look at the `killall` command, which can take a process name as argument. Much simpler than `ps | grep`. Also, the `yes` command can be used to pipe `y` to a process (if it doesn't support an appropriate command).

Comment: Why is it giving that error?

Comment: Is `pkill` is installed on your Unix distro ? Take a look to it if yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: by saying *pid of file "File_name"* i guess that you mean *the pid of process having "File_name" in it's argument list*

First, you should remove the bogus "/directory>" prefix of the last line of script (what did you intend to do with this ?)

And the 1st line should better be written:

- if you do'nt have "pkill" command:

  ```
  ps -aef | awk '/File_name/ && ! /awk/ {system("kill -9 " $2)}'
  ```
- if you have it:

  ```
  pkill -9 -f "File_name"
  ```